# Jenkins build hangs if Android device not available

Tags: android, timeout, jenkins, adb, jenkins-plugins

We have a step in our Jenkins build script that attempts to uninstall some unit tests from a device using a command that looks like this:

```
adb uninstall com.company.test
```

If the physical device that we normally have connected to our build machine is not present or off for some reason, the build will just hang saying:

```
waiting for device -
```

Does anyone know how to work around this? I've heard rumors of some plugin? Ideally, we'd like it to just spit out a warning after some timeout period and then just continue. Next most ideal would be to fire up an emulator instead.

Comment: can you not call `adb devices` and only continue if this returns at least 1 device

Comment: What are the rumours you've heard? There's an Android Emulator Plugin, but it currently doesn't detect a missing device in its install/uninstall build steps (though I guess that could be added).

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but the Build Timeout plugin will at least keep the build from hanging forever: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

A hacky workaround is to check if the 'adb devices' command returns anything other than the "List of devices attached" string.

In your script, try adding:

```
DEVICE_PRESENT=`adb devices | tail -n 1`
if [ -n "$DEVICE_PRESENT" ]
then
    echo "A device is present..."
    # Run your uninstall and other commands you need the device for here
fi
```

The only reason this hack works is that 'adb devices' currently returns "List of devices attached" and an empty line (if there are no devices found). If this behavior ever changes then this approach will no longer work.